# Modelica evaluation of an expression

Tags: modelica

I'm new to Modelica, and I'm wondering, what would be the evaluation of rA within model B.
Is the value 5 or 11 ?

```
model A
    Real rA = 1 + rB;
    Real rB = 4;
    
    model B
        Real rB = 10;
        // Case A : Evaluation of rA = 1 + 4 = 5 
        // Case B : Evaluation of rA = 1 + 10 = 11 
    end B;
end A;
```

**Edit** : what would be the evaluation of rD in model A using the code below ?
Is the value 5 or 11 ?

```
model A
    Real rA = 1 + rB;
    Real rB = 4;

    model B
        Real rB = 10;
        Real rC = rA;
    end B;

    B myB;
    

    Real rD = myB.rC;

    // What is the result of the evaluation of rD ?
    // Case A : Evaluation of rD = 1 + 4 = 5 
    // Case B : Evaluation of rD = 1 + 10 = 11
end A;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rD = 1 + 4. The rB in model B is not involved in the calculation of rC (or rA). The expression is not like a C macro that is evaluated in that context again.
If you want to have the behavior that myB.rB influences the calculation of myB.rC then you need to change your code.

```
model A
    Real rA = 1 + rB;
    Real rB = 4;

    model B
        Real rB = 10;
        Real rC = 1 + rB;
    end B;

    B myB;
    

    Real rD = myB.rC;

    // What is the result of the evaluation of rD?
    // Case B : Evaluation of rD = 1 + 10 = 11
end A;
```

or make a function if that expression is complicated:

```
model A
    function f
       input Real x;
       output Real y;
    algorithm
       y := 1 + x;
    end f;
    Real rA = f(rB);
    Real rB = 4;

    model B
        Real rB = 10;
        Real rC = f(rB);
    end B;

    B myB;
    

    Real rD = myB.rC;

    // What is the result of the evaluation of rD?
    // Case B : Evaluation of rD = 1 + 10 = 11
end A;
```

Answer (score 1):

Model `B` is not instantiated so `B.rB=10` is not "known" by model `A`. Thus, `rA` = 5

If you want the result to be 11 then the code should be something like:

```
model A
    B b;
    Real rA = 1 + rB;
    Real rB = b.rB;
    
    model B
        Real rB = 10;
        // Case A : Evaluation of rA = 1 + 4 = 5 
        // Case B : Evaluation of rA = 1 + 10 = 11 
    end B;
end A;
```

Comment: I have edited my question to add more clarity to what I want to know